# How to add a cron task

Tags: hooks

I am new to drupal, now I have function get_node_from_rss() which the file is inside mysite\sites\all\modules\node\node_rss\node_from_rss.module the function will update node from the rss link every 1 hour. Now, I dun know how to make this function add to the cron task. Can I run it without using cron.php? I search in google, they something like simple change the function name like get_node_from_rss_cron(), I also putting some code like:

```
$interval = variable_get('get_node_from_rss_interval', 60 * 60);
if (time() >= variable_get('get_node_from_rss_next_execution', 0)) {
   watchdog('get_node_from_rss', 'get_node_from_rss ran');
   if (!empty($GLOBALS['wowfi_locamusic_addnode_show_status_message'])) {
     drupal_set_message(t('wowfi_locamusic_addnode executed at %time', array('%time' => date_iso8601(time(0)))));
     drupal_set_message(t('wowfi_locamusic_addnode executed at %time', array('%time' => date_iso8601(time(0)))));
    }
    variable_set('wowfi_locamusic_addnode_next_execution', time() + $interval);
  }
```

inside my code, but those still not working for me,
Any solution?

Comment: So you've written this in a custom module?  Or you written it in the core node module?

Comment: Change `get_node_from_rss_cron()` to `node_rss_cron()` and `node_from_rss.module` filename to `node_rss.module`. And don't put your custom module inside core modules.

Comment: `get_node_from_rss_cron()` this is incorrect. Cron Functions should be of format `MODULE_NAME_cron()`. Any hook should follow this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *hook* implementation is simply a **my_module_name**_function implentation. 
Your module's internal name is what you have used in the .module file's name.

So for in this case, it's `node_from_rss` (I'd recommend you to rename the folder name to node_from_rss as well so it reduces any confusion).

If you rename your cron function to comply with the above **my_module_name**_function pattern, function name has to be `node_from_rss_cron`

```
function node_from_rss_cron() {
 $interval = variable_get('get_node_from_rss_interval', 60 * 60);
 if (time() >= variable_get('get_node_from_rss_next_execution', 0)) {
   watchdog('get_node_from_rss', 'get_node_from_rss ran');
   if (!empty($GLOBALS['wowfi_locamusic_addnode_show_status_message'])) {
     drupal_set_message(t('wowfi_locamusic_addnode executed at %time', array('%time' => date_iso8601(time(0)))));
     drupal_set_message(t('wowfi_locamusic_addnode executed at %time', array('%time' => date_iso8601(time(0)))));
    }
    variable_set('wowfi_locamusic_addnode_next_execution', time() + $interval);
  }
}
```

Other than these changes, here are some of the Drupal best practices.

Drupal 7 has a `REQUEST_TIME` constant defined at the beginning of page processing. If this code is for D7, use it instead of time().

drupal_set_message() function sets a message to the screen. but cron functions will run without use interaction. You will not see this message unless you are running cron manually at admin/reports/status page.

Avoid placing folders such as 'node' inside sites/all/modules folder. Technically it's completely ok to do so. But I think it will confuse you and others in the long run. Usually we place modules like:

```
sites/all/modules/MY_MODULE/MY_MODULE.module
```

Comment: Just an FYI `drupal_set_message` is of no use inside a cron function unless you are debugging and calling cron function explicitly. Better to use `watchdog` all time

Comment: that mean i should put as mysite\sites\all\modules\node\node_from_rss.module? i thought all custom module should put like mysite\sites\all\modules\node\node_rss\node_from_rss.module, cause i got another 2 custom module also put at the folder. Another question, if this module disable at admin module setting the cron still working?

Comment: If you disable it, no hook will be fired. You can't use functions in disabled modules either.